How do I make two objects deform correctly?
I am making a detailed 3D model of a Shed and I want to animate it assembling. I have two identical sheets of iron that need to be overlapped. I have animated them coming together and they clip (as expected). However, I would like them to deform - the sheet on the inside bends in and the sheet on the outside bends out - as they would when you would assemble it in real life. Is there a way to do that?
I have explored using physics but I couldn't get anything to work (however I am a novice in Blender, especially physics).
Would somebody be able to help me out?


hello could you please show a drawing of them before and after? It's not clear how they bend in and out

They don't bend at the moment. I would like to make them bend. I'm just not sure how to

Could you use the Annotate tool to draw (even "quick & dirty" !) on the first view you have posted how the dark and light oranges lines should deformed, exaggerating the displacement to help to understand your objective ?

Maybe shapekeys? But as we say, it's not clear what you want
